# How to prevent users of different virtual host to chat with each other in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I have a ejabberd installation and I'm trying to restrict users from chatting with other users in different virtual hosts but not sure how to do it. Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box, but a simple module (with a function hooked on `filter_packet`) can do the trick.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how I can achieve this? I'm new to Ejabberd.

Comment: In order to write such a module you need to know Erlang and a bit of ejabberd internals. So, no simple advice.

Comment: I can manage that. Any link that can point me to that direction?

Comment: Just wrote it, here you are: https://gist.github.com/zinid/2525b45610422838c87b88f2847f9bfe
Note, the module will only work for ejabberd 17.03 and newer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. That helped. I used your code and recompiled ejabberd and its working fine now. Thank you very much. This is awesome. Please do leave an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just for the record, the module is now a part of ejabberd-contrib, so you can install it using ejabberdctl command interface.